# Hibernate, Extending Entity - "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity"

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I have a Hibernate Entity, `BaseEvent`, which works fine:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "base_event")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "seq")
public class BaseEvent
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected Long id = null;

    @Column(name = "my_field", nullable = false)
    protected String myField;

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMyField()
    {
        return myField;
    }

    public void setMyField(final String myField)
    {
        this.myField = myField;
    }
}
```

I want to identify when this object is changed and update some `Map` in my application. The easiest way I could think of doing this was to extend `BaseEvent` and override the setter:

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;

public class ExtendedEvent extends BaseEvent
{
    @Override
    public void setMyField(final String myField)
    {
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Setting myField to {0}", myField));
        super.setMyField(myField);
    }
}
```

This works fine in my application, but then when I come to persist the Entity, Hibernate complains it doesn't know what an `ExtendedEvent` is.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: my.package.ExtendedEvent
```

I can see that extending Hibernate Entities is a non-trivial problem, especially when you start adding fields - but all I want is for Hibernate to treat `ExtendedEvent` as a `BaseEvent` (because it is). Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: Would you please define the ExtendedEvent as Hibernate entity by removing the table name from BaseEvent.

Comment: @Jackson I need to define the table name as it's not the same as the name of the class, and Hibernate isn't creating the database.

Comment: *I can see that extending Hibernate Entities is a non-trivial problem* I would say contrary - it is trivial. Either extend class or embed fields.

Answer (score 0):

Make base event `@MappedSuperclass` and extending class `@Entity`

so

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEvent
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(whatever)
public class ExtendedEvent extends BaseEvent
```

Comment: Thanks but this is unfortunately the opposite of what I want - I want to keep all the declarations in one place and be able to persist either a `BaseEvent` or an `ExtendedEvent`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your map only when changes are updated in the data store, I would recommend implementing [onFlushDirty in a Hibernate Interceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html#onFlushDirty(java.lang.Object,%20java.io.Serializable,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.String[],%20org.hibernate.type.Type[])). This method gets called whenever the Session is flushed to the database for every entity change. You can check the object type in the onFlushDirty method for your entity of interest and property of interest.

Comment: Thankyou, that's a really cool feature - but unfortunately in my case the object is being created and modified in several ways before being persisted and it's this stage I'm working in.

Comment: You could also use Aspects, create a pointcut on the setter and update the map in your application